# Evaluate $\tan^{-1} (\tan (x + \frac{\pi}{3}))$, where $x\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

This is a simplified version of a much complex question, but the problem I have is mainly conceptual.

Going by the form we have, the answer should simply be $x+\frac{\pi}{3}$, but it doesn’t account for the fact that when $x\to \frac{\pi}{2}$, the domain of the function isn’t satisfied

Do we need to make any changes to angle to fit it into the proper domain, or is writing it directly fine?

Edit: According to the answer, it is supposed to be written directly

Comment: yeah the function is undefined when $x = \frac\pi6$

Comment: Cosider breaking the domain in $(0,\frac{\pi}{6}) $ and $(\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{2})$.

Comment: it could help you to consider $\tan (x+\frac{\pi}{3}) =\tan (y)$ and start from there

Comment: Re "   According to the answer, it is supposed to be written directly "    You need to define the range of $tan^{-1} x$ and $\tan x$.  It is usually taken as  $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ for $tan^{-1} x$. Also for "the domain of the function isn’t satisfied"  the  domain of $\tan x $ and $tan^{-1} x$ need to stated explicitly to allow a meaningful answer

Answer (score 1):

For me, it should be written as
\begin{cases}
x+\dfrac \pi 3&\text{ if}\quad 0<x<\frac\pi6 ,\\[1ex]
x-\dfrac{2\pi}3 &\text{ if}\quad \frac\pi6 <x <\frac\pi 2.
\end{cases}